# What is the meaning of 結構もった方じゃないか

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is the meaning of 結構もった in phrases like

> 結構もった方じゃないか
> 結構もった方だと思います

Answer (score 4, accepted):

もつ in such a phrase means "hang on", "keep up", or "stay good". From the definition #9 in [this dictionary entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/219381/meaning/m0u/):

> ９ 長くそのままの状態を保ち続ける。もちこたえる。「夏場でも―・つ食品」「これじゃとてもからだが―・たない

In this sense, もつ can be also written as 保つ in kanji.

Depending on the subject, 結構もつ can mean "(for a battery/food) to have a longer life than expected", "(for a person) to hang on for quite some time before giving up", and so on.

Comment: I have never seen 保つ read as もつ; only たもつ.  Can you give a reference to where this happens?

Comment: My IME (ATOK) converts もつ to 保つ. See [this](http://www.kanjijiten.net/jiten/4251.html#k4261), [this](http://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanjib/806.html), and [this](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/satox/20121005/1349486693). I guess 保【たも】つ is transitive and 保【も】つ is intransitive.