# Expressing "for/in exchange for"

Tags: particles, conditionals

I'm trying to say something like "how much EXP do you get for defeating that monster?" Is there a particle I should be using here?

My attempt is this:

そのモンスターを倒したらどれくらいの経験値が貰えるの？

But at least to my native-English-speaking brain, this feels more like "how much EXP do you get IF you defeat that monster?" whereas I'm looking more for something that takes the monster-defeating as a given. But perhaps I'm just thinking too much from an English perspective here, so I'd appreciate any clarification. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How much EXP do you get for defeating that monster?"

```
          -------->
```

1. そのモンスター撃退で得られる経験値は？

   ```
   そのモンスター撃退によって得られる経験値は？  

   そのモンスター撃退により ........
   ```

My favorite:

2. そのモンスターを撃退して得られる経験値は？

( [1.で] and  [2.て] are both Te-forms ) . . .  [1.で] is  a Te-form, the same as the example (6) below.

See:  [What is the role of あるいて?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38564/what-is-the-role-of-%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6/38582#38582)

```
(5) a.  公園でポピーに会って, ヒューはとても喜んだ｡ 
    b.  [Bumping into] Poppy in the park, [Hugh] was very pleased.
          Having bumped into ... , 

(6) a.  今日は土曜日で, ヒューは学校がある｡ 
    b.  Today being Saturday, [Hugh] has school.

(7) a.  正直に言って, クーは太りすぎだ｡ 
    b.  Honestly speaking, Koo is overweight.
```

---

P.S.  ---  I think Mr. Chocolate is correct in pointing out that the DE in
 [ そのモンスター撃退で得られる経験値は？ ]  is not a Te-form.

I think the following examples use the Te-form.  (Ok, maybe not the last two.) So the distinction is pretty tricky.

- そのモンスター撃退で経験値は何点来る？
- そのモンスター撃退で 経験値は何点 得られるの？
- そのモンスター撃沈で どれだけ経験値が得られる？
- そのモンスター撃沈で何点の経験値をゲット？
- そのモンスター撃沈で増える経験値は？ ----  ( or 貰える )
- そのモンスター撃退で来る経験値は何点？

Comment: The で in モンスター撃退**で** is [the case particle/格助詞「で」](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/148951/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A7/), and it's not the conjuncitive particle で cos 撃退 is a noun, and it's not the continuative form of the assertive auxiliary だ either cos this sentence can't be rephrased *そのモンスター撃退だ, whereas the で in 今日は土曜日**で** is [the continuative form of assertive auxiliary/断定の助動詞「だ」](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/132198/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A0/)

Comment: (cont.) cos you can say it as 今日は土曜日だ. And [the で as the te-form is a conjunctive particle/接続助詞](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/148952/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A7/) （＝[conjunctive particle/接続助詞「て」](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/148945/meaning/m0u/)). Are Japanese learners taught that the case particle で and the continuative form of the assertive auxiliary だ are also て形/te-form?

Comment: Thank you!  I think you're right.  I'm going to add a P.S.

Comment: `Mr. chocolate` <- Ms です、一応・・・^ ^;

Answer (score 6):

Your translation attempt looks already perfect to me, but if you want to translate even more literally, you can say:

> そのモンスターを**倒すことで**どれくらいの経験値が貰えるの？

こと after a verb is a *nominalizer*, which turns verbs into nouns, like `-ing` in English. で is the particle which corresponds to `by` or `for` in this case.

Optionally you can also say:

> そのモンスターを**倒すこと[によって](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%AB%E5%9B%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6)**どれくらいの経験値が貰えるの？

...but this may be a bit too stiff in a sentence like this.