# 2 verbs link together ?

Tags: verbs, て-form

I'm a bit confuse while trying to read a few sentences.

1. **離れて見る**と、彼は実際よりずっと若く見える。(離れる + 見る）(I understand the first phrase mean "from distance view")
2. 相手の名前をなかなか思い出すことが**できなくて困った** (this is either "2 verbs link together "できる + 困る or the "て" here mean "when/because" and not a modifier for "困った")

So i translate the 2nd sentence into this:

=> It's troublesome **when** cannot remember your partner's name (i think this one is correct) 
=> It's cannot be trouble ... (this sound so wrong)

I only learned that "て" mean "when/because" when you use it with a **comma** to separate 2 sentences.

eg: 事故が**あって**、バスが遅れてしまいました。

I feel like I'm missing somethings during my Japanese's studying progress.. Is this a grammar structure or is there a way to call this type of combination ?

Thank you, sorry for my noobness !

Comment: Are you asking if the inclusion of a comma affects the meaning when using て to connect verbs?

Comment: 「相手の名前をなかなか思い出すことができなくて、困った。」(with a comma)「事故があってバスが遅れてしまいました。」(without a comma) would be okay. I think commas are often optional, as long as the sentence is not difficult to parse/read/understand. 「ご飯を食べてシャワーを浴びて寝ました。」「地震があって大勢の人が死にました。」「お腹が空いていてケーキを二つ食‌​べてしまいました。」(without commas) look okay to me, too. Just 「この机は、私が木を使って、作りました。」(with another comma) looks unnatural. I can't explain well, but I think it's probably because it has too many commas in one short sentence.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of て as having 3 basic uses.

The first is to show **sequence**. A happens, then B, then C. ご飯を食べて、シャワーを浴びて、寝ました。*I ate my meal, then took a shower and then slept.*

The second is to show **means, method**. A is used to do B. この机は、私が木を使って作りました。*As for this table, I made it by using wood.*

The third is to show **reason**. 地震があって、大勢の人が死にました。*Because an earthquake happened, lots of people died.*

---

Perhaps you could now think about how each of your two examples fits in with one of the three usages of て.

For me, I think of it this way:

離れて見る can be thought of as the second usage: ***Through/by** being at a distance, I (or some other person) look(s) or see(s) something.* The method of seeing or viewing - the "how" - is by being far away.

事故があって、バスが遅れてしまいました。can be thought of as the third usage: *The bus was late **because** an accident happened.* (note the nuance of regret or disappointment that I can't really incorporate in the translation. This is because of てしまいました.) て in this case shows reason.

---

Note: the third usage of て, to show reason, is limited by at least two rules. When you construct a sentence with "reason て result", what follows the て must be non-volitional (cannot be controlled / happens naturally). Furthermore, the reason must not happen after the result.

For example (edited with chocolate's suggested sentences):

> X お[腹]{なか}が[空]{す}いていて、ケーキを二つ食べましょう。(volitional)
>
> O お腹が空いて‌​いるので/から、ケーキを二つ食べましょう‌​。(ので and から can take volition)
>
> O お腹が空いていて、ケーキを二つ食‌​べ(てしまい)ました。/食べられました。‌(て with non-volition)
>
> X 友達があした来て、きょうはいそがしくなりました。 *Because my friend is coming tomorrow, today became busy (became a busy day).* My friend coming tomorrow happens, chronologically speaking, after today became busy. Thus the sentence becomes ungrammatical.
>
> O  友達があした来ます**から**、きょうはいそがしくなりました。*Because my friend is coming tomorrow, today became busy (became a busy day).* から is able to express a reason happening after a result, so this sentence is acceptable.

Comment: 「うれしくて、ケーキを食べました」「うれしくて、ケーキを食べられました」 sound unnatural... "Volitional" is 「食べよう」「食べましょう」, right? How about using something like「×お[腹]{なか}が[空]{す}いていて、ケーキを二つ食べましょう。←volitional」→「○お腹が空いている**ので/から**、ケーキを二つ食べましょう。」「○お腹が空いていて、ケーキを二つ食べ(てしまい)ました。/食べられました。←non-volitional」 instead?

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'll edit these in later; for now I will add a note linking to your comment:)

Comment: No problem! Added chocolate's recommended examples.

Answer (score 1):

The て form should be seen as a way of concatenating sentences in one whole sentence.

Instead of saying

> 事故がありました。そして、バスが遅れてしまいました。

You would connect those sentences in one, as in

> 事故があって、バスが遅れてしまいました。

It can be generally seen as an "and".

In this example, it would be literally translated as

> There was an accident and the bus was late.

In this case, it obviously shows a cause-to-effect connection, but this is not always true.

In your example, I would say you could translate the sentence as

> It was troublesome I could not recall my partner's name.

Since you could literally translate it as

> I could not recall my partner's name. And it was troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

> . . . できなくて困った
>
> 事故があって、バスが遅れてしまいました。

In each of these examples (above), a reason is given.

-- like (5) and (6) below.

See:  [What is the role of あるいて?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38564/what-is-the-role-of-%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6/38582#38582)

```
(5) a.  公園でポピーに会って, ヒューはとても喜んだ｡ 
    b.  [Bumping into] Poppy in the park, [Hugh] was very pleased.
          Having bumped into ... , 

(6) a.  今日は土曜日で, ヒューは学校がある｡ 
    b.  Today being Saturday, [Hugh] has school.

(7) a.  正直に言って, クーは太りすぎだ｡ 
    b.  Honestly speaking, Koo is overweight.
```