# What is the meaning of スタンドプレイ in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, words, loanwords

I know スタンドプレイ is the action of showing off, but what does it mean in this sentence? Is it an action or an adjective?

> スタンドプレイで己の望むままに生きる。

My attempt: "He is an exhibitionist and he lives as he likes".

There isn't much context, it's just a character being presented. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, "スタンドプレイ" is Japanes English to mean "playing to the grandstand." But I take "スタンドプレイで己の望むままに生きる"  as "I live my own way by being self-assertive."

"スタンドプレイ" is a noun, which can be verbalized as "スタンドプレイをする." But "スタンドプレイ" here refers to one's hehavior and attitude rather than action.

Answer (score 1):

In Japan, people who stand out are disliked.
Because disturbing the team work.
Grandstanding (スタンドプレー) means that "selfish"

Answer (score 0):

Someone's motto (or short manifesto)

> スタンドプレイで己の望むままに生きる。

I will be showy and going my own way.

> [https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/スタンドプレイ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4)  -- 
>   スタンド・プレイは、異なる分野で2種類の意味で使われる。 スポーツ[編集]. 野球、バスケットボールなどの団体競技で、チームの勝利よりも個人が自身の成績を優先したり目立つことを目的にしたプレイ。 本来は grandstand play / grand stand play で、英語圏 ...

スタンド‐プレー １ スポーツなどで、観衆の拍手喝采(かっさい)をねらってする、はでなプレー。 ２ 自分を強く印象づけるための、目立つ行為。

I'm trying to think ... who was the 1st such anime/manga character ?

Maybe ... ( 矢吹ジョー or his rival 力石徹 ) or 番場蛮

> 番場蛮がイラスト付きでわかる！ 「侍ジャイアンツ」に登場 バン・ババーン 概要 土佐出身の主人公。高校は中退している。 目上の人に対しても丁寧語を使わない性格で、ギャグシーンがもっとも多い。 頭に血が上りやすく感情に任せて行動をしてしまう部分もあっ ...

---

> スタンドプレイで

I think this is similar to スタンドプレイをして

This DE is tricky.  DE is the Te-form of DA.

> スタンドプレイで己の望むままに生きる。

スタンドプレイで modifies 生きる。

While being Stand-Play-ish, I'm going to live exactly/freely as I want.

Always being Stand-Play-ish, I'm going to live exactly/freely as I want.

See:  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38582/16344

```
(5) a.  公園でポピーに会って, ヒューはとても喜んだ｡ 
    b.  [Bumping into] Poppy in the park, [Hugh] was very pleased.
          Having bumped into ... , 

(6) a.  今日は土曜日で, ヒューは学校がある｡ 
    b.  Today being Saturday, [Hugh] has school.

(7) a.  正直に言って, クーは太りすぎだ｡ 
    b.  Honestly speaking, Koo is overweight.
```

Comment: Thank you! But what is it grammatically here? A な adjective with で used as a conjunction? Lexically speaking, can it have a nuance of "haughty", "pretentious"?