# Is the で here connecting the two sentences or does it act as a context particle?

Tags: grammar, particle-で

Is the で after おかげ a て-form or the context particle?

> 友達のおかげで、映画はただで見られた。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 友達のおかげ**で**、映画はただで見られた。

It's the case particle で. It's not the te-form of a verb because おかげ is not a verb but a noun: the polite prefix お + a noun 陰. The で is not the 連用形(continuative form) of the assertive auxiliary だ either, because your sentence is not two sentences 「友達のおかげだった。そして映画はただで見られた。」

Comment: 「映画をタダで見られたのは**友達のおかげで** 、ご飯をタダで食べられたのは先輩のおかげだ。」とか言ったら、「おかげで」の「で」は断定の助動詞「だ」の連用形「で」になりますね・・

Comment: i'm still a newbie, so this will be hard. 1.You said that "今日は土曜で、田中は学校がある。"(I hate the name Hugh) consists of 2 sentences because each phrases has a subject/topic. While in "友達のおかげで、映画はただで見られた" is a single sentence. But the subject/topic can be the same and thus be omitted right? Just like how "I am A,(I am)B,and(I am)C. 3 sentences! (映画は)友達のおかげで、(映画は)ただで見られた。I could not differentiate if the で is the continuative form or the context/case particle in sentences like this and I want to know how! 2.It's really possible to have 2 or more context/case particles in a sentence??! ただで and 友達のおかげで?

Comment: 3.Is it possible to construct a compound sentence with both verbs and state of beings in Japanese, like : I am a student and I study everyday (私は学生で(でして)、毎日勉強している。)??!

Comment: 1. Your original sentence cannot be rephrased as「映画は友達のおかげで、映画はタダで見られた」, because you don't say 映画は友達のおかげだ. You can say 映画を見られたのは友達のおかげだ but 映画は友達ののおかげだ sounds strange. In your sentence, 友達のおかげで(Thanks to a friend) adverbially modifies タダで見られた, and it can be rephrased 映画は、友達のおかげでタダで見られた, where 友達のおかげで adverbially modifies 見られた. To differentiate, you should split the sentence using だ or であり, and check if it's correct and makes sense. 2. I don't see why not. eg 「自分の部屋で一人で寝る。」「まな板の上で包丁でニンニクをたたきつぶす」

Comment: 3. Yes, 「私は学生で、毎日勉強している。」 sounds good to me.  (You could also say politely/formally: 「私は学生で(して)、毎日勉強しています。/しております。」. 「でして」「～おります」 would sound more formal.)

Answer (score 0):

> 友達の おかげ で、映画はただで見られた。

The meaning is :  "Thanks to my friend(s), . . . "

のおかげで by grace of,  by virtue of,  It's thanks to,  owing to

Literaly :  (Because of) being owing to my friend(s), . . . ( literal tr. is esp. hard because of おかげ )

Here, のおかげで is a Te-form of のおかげだ --- Same as the example (6) below  : "Today being Saturday, . . . "

See:  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38582/16344

```
(5) a.  公園でポピーに会って, ヒューはとても喜んだ｡ 
    b.  [Bumping into] Poppy in the park, [Hugh] was very pleased.
          Having bumped into ... , 

(6) a.  今日は土曜日で, ヒューは学校がある｡ 
    b.  Today being Saturday, [Hugh] has school.

(7) a.  正直に言って, クーは太りすぎだ｡ 
    b.  Honestly speaking, Koo is overweight.
```

---

> Is the で after おかげ a て-form or the context particle?

Wow!  i had no idea that this is such a hard question.  I believe that in some fundamental sense, there is no difference between the two for おかげで

Several Web sites seem to classify おかげで as [て形], but maybe if i check closely, they may contain restrictions or limitations.

- 友達の おかげ で、映画はただで見られた。
- タダ券の おかげ で、映画はただで見られた。
- 今日が土曜日なのと タダ券の おかげ で、映画はただで見られた。
- 友達のタダ券の おかげ で、映画はただで見られた。
- 友達がくれたタダ券の おかげ で、映画はただで見られた。
- 友達がタダ券をくれた おかげ で、映画はただで見られた。
- 友達がタダ券を送ってくれた おかげ で、映画はただで見られた。
- 今日は土曜日で 友達がタダ券を送ってくれた おかげ で、映画はただで見られた。
- 今日が土曜日なのと 友達がタダ券を送ってくれた おかげ で、映画はただで見られた。

Comment: The で in (6)今日は土曜日**で** 、ヒューは学校がある is not the te-form of a verb, cos 土曜日 is not a verb. It's the 連用形(continuative form) of the 断定の助動詞(assertive auxiliary) だ, cos the sentence is 「今日は土曜日だ。だから、ヒューは学校がある。 」←今日は土曜日で(だ) is a complete sentence, cos it has a subject 今日は. So the で cannot be the case particle で.

Comment: You should parse them as「｛今日が土曜日なのとタダ券｝のおかげで」(noun+の+nounおかげ+case particleで) ・「｛友達がタダ券をくれた｝おかげで」(relative clause+nounおかげ+case particleで)・「｛（友達がくれた）タダ券｝の おかげで」(relative clause+noun+の+おかげ+で), etc... then you'll see the で is a case particle. None of them is a complete sentence. Are you insisting that 「noun+で」 is a te-form? Is that what's usually taught to Japanese learners?

Comment: I mean, do they teach 断定の助動詞『だ』の連用形『で』 as a kind of て形 to people learning Japanese as a foreign language?

Comment: 「今日は土曜で明日は日曜だ」の「で」は、 "te-form of *the copula*" と説明されているのを見たことがあります。 http://www.japaneseprofessor.com/reference/grammar/conjugations-of-the-japanese-copula/ もちろん「友達のおかげで」の「で」は別物です。（どちらも名詞の直後に来るという意味では似て見えますが）

Comment: @naruto おおっ、そうなんですね・・　（「友達のおかげで」の「で」は格助詞ですよね・・。で、格助詞の「（名詞）＋で」まで、「て形」のひとつとして教えられていたりしませんよね・・まさかね・・）

Comment: 流石に「海で泳ぐ」とか「包丁で野菜を切る」の「で」をテ形と呼ぶ人はいないと思います…たぶん