# The role of を in this phrase 夜景を背景に歌舞伎の映像が流れます

Tags: particles

I am reading this article http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20161005/k10010718561000.html and come across this phrase:

> 夜景を背景に歌舞伎の映像が流れます

I can get the general meaning but I'm not clear on what is the role of を in the sentence.

Comment: 夜景を背景に==With the [night sky] as the [background] ...   　　ObjをNounにする　（as in　エビを天ぷらにする、　ドアを背にする、　ゴールを目前にする）　　( The て-form　＝　ObjをNounにして )　　Please see:　http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/39611/16344

Comment: @HizHa 最後のそのリンク、「te-formとは何か説明しましょう」という意図ですか？もうそれ、聞かれてることと無関係ですよね？