# Which part is ではない negating?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I recently read this Japanese sentence:

> 他の感情に比べて、そういう感情が特別のものとして取り上げて強いわけではない。

and was not sure which part does ではない negate.

1. Does it negate *特別のものとして取り上げて*, which means そういう感情が特別のものとして取り上げていない。そういう感情が強い.
2. Does it negate *強い*, which means そういう感情が特別のものとして取り上げている。そういう感情が強くない。
3. Does it negate both, which means そういう感情が特別のものとして取り上げていない。そういう感情が強くない。

Answer (score 1):

That ない directly negates わけ, indirectly negating "そういう感情が特別のものとして取り上げて強い" as a whole.

- ～わけでは**ない**。
  It's **not** that ～. / It does **not** mean ～.
- そういう感情が強いわけではない。
  It's not that such emotions are strong.

特別のものとして取り上げて describes 強い like this:

> そういう感情が[特別のものとして取り上げて→]強いわけではない。
>
> It's not that such emotions are strong [←in a way it can be singled out as something special].
> → Such emotions are not strong enough to be singled out as something special.

特別のものとして取り上げる is "to pick something up as something special", and it adverbially modifies 強い using the te-form. This type of 取り上げて is not very common, but [取り立てて(～ない)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42867/5010) is a common phrase that effectively means "(not) in particular".