# Why does "hajimete" mean "for the first time"?

Tags: verbs, etymology, idioms

はじめて(hajimete) is the te-form of the verb はじめる(hajimeru) - to begin. How come it means "for the first time" and is used appropriately to mean the whole phrase? Is it an idiom?

Answer (score 6):

There are two kanji with the same kun-reading "haji-". The kanji for [*hajimete*](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%88%9D%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6) meaning "for the first time" is [初](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%88%9D%20%23kanji), which means *initial*, *first*, or *beginning* but does not mean *to begin*. Don't mix it with [始](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%A7%8B%20%23kanji), which means *to begin*.

And yes, some te-forms have lexicalized and idiomatic meanings, and I think 初めて is one of them. You can see similar examples in this question: [What is the role of あるいて?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38564/5010)