# Verb in て-form before a noun

Tags: て-form, phrases, adverbial

I came across this sentence:

> 「東京」は、京都から見て東の京（首都）という意味です。

I don't understand why there 見る is in て-form. I've never met uses of て-form before a noun. To me it looks like a typo. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a typo. You have to remember ～から見て as a set phrase meaning "seen from ～" or "from the viewpoint of ～". See:  [What is the role of あるいて?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38564/5010)

For example:

> 私から見て彼は十分に強い。
> He is strong enough in my view.

There are also many te-forms that are almost like fixed adverbs, for example 初めて, 取り立てて, 重ねて and まして.