# What does 結構好きです mean?

Tags: translation, adverbs

What does 結構好き in

> このシチュエイションが**結構好き**です。

mean? Does it just mean "great"?

Comment: Have you at least looked up a dictionary?

Comment: Dictionary has many translations, like: great, good, fine, enough, thanks.

Comment: So, 結構好きです has some NEGATIVE in many situation.

Answer (score 3):

結構 is an adverb whose meaning is (here) "quite". So 結構好き means "quite like".

So your sentence 「このシチュエイションが**結構**好きです」 means "I **quite** like this situation" / "I am **quite** fond of this situation."

Comment: I can use google translate too, but "quite like" is wrong in this case, I think. My sentence is "このシチュエイションが結構好きです".

Comment: What's wrong with "I **quite** like this situation" / "I am **quite** fond of this situation"?

Comment: @user3073836 I don't think this answer is based on Google Translate.

Comment: Yea, "I quite like this situation" / "I am quite fond of this situation" looks right. Thanks all.

Comment: This is problem. 結構好きです has  some negative smell, too.

Comment: ＠Waki 上の質問者のコメントの通り、原文は「このシチュエイションが結構好きです。」ですが、それを踏まえて回答・コメントされているのでしょうか。。。？ 「このシチュエイションが結構好きです。」を "But I like this situation." と訳すのは、かなり無理があると思いますが。。

Comment: @chocolate 結構好きの翻訳についてですが。

Comment: I think what Waki-san is getting at is that the 結構 qualifies  (though does not negate) rather than reinforces  the statement "...が好きです。" The 結構 is added, the chiebukuro answer says, so that it's easier for the speaker to change their position in accordance with what others think. I don't know about this claim, but it's true that 結構 can have a smack of conservativeness or non-commitment, which the word "quite" does in this case (or does not?)

Answer (score 0):

> https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/29019/16344 
>   Depending on the subject, 結構もつ can mean "(for a battery/food) to have a longer life than expected", "(for a person) to hang on for quite some time before giving up", and so on.

Longer / better "than expected" -- Yes, that's it.

Or,  to make it more explicit (and spelling it out)  :

> http://gogen-allguide.com/ke/kekkou.html  
>   【意味】 　　結構とは、見事であること。満足できる状態であるさま。それ以上必要としないさま。
>
> 【結構の語源・由来】 　　漢語の「結構」は、建造物の構造や文章の構成など、組み立てや構成を意味する名詞である。
>   この「結構」が日本に入り、「計画」「もくろみ」「支度」「準備」といった意味の名詞として用いられるようになった。
>   さらに、その準備や計画を「立派だ」「よろしい」と評価する用法が生まれ、結構は「丁寧だ」「人柄が良い」といった意味でも使われるようになった。
>
> 断りの言葉として用いる「もう結構です」は、近代以降に見られる表現で、「十分満足しているから、これ以上必要ない」といったニュアンスから生まれたもの。
>
> 「結構おいしい」 「結構楽しい」 などの副詞は、「 *十分とは言えないが、思っていたよりも良い（満足できる）* 」の意味からである。

So, the adverb 「結構」 means:  かなり（良い）、わりと（良い）、比較的（良い）、 == It's pretty good, (not, "It's very good.")

> このシチュエイションが結構好きです。

- I like this situation (or story setting?) pretty good.
- This situation is pretty good.

But perhaps (compared to 30 years ago), younger folks may be more often using it to mean "very much" -- because of [ understatement becomes superlative ]  logic

----- So much so that many teenagers today may not even be aware of this traditional, older meaning: 十分とは言えないが、思っていたよりも良い（満足できる）

<sub>I'm pretty certain that かなり好き、わりと好き (esp. the former, and esp. with special intonation) have undergone the [ understatement becomes superlative ] transformation.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

結構です means "No, thank you". 結構好きです means "but, I like it".
http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13116051673

Comment: Using "but, I like it" depends highly on the context, and I don't think It's a general context...

Comment: @Yuki Inoue http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13116051673

Comment: That chiebukuro's question/answer are both highly contextual, whereas this question is not... I still think this answer is not suited taking into account of the shared link.